# Julia: How to find the longest word in a given string?

Tags: function, julia

I am very new in Julia, I got this challenge from the web:

How can I find the longest word in a given string?

I would like to build a function which would allow to obtain the longest string, even in cases where punctuation is used.

I was trying to to the following code:

```
function LongestWord(sen::String)
sentence =maximum(length(split(sen, "")))
word= [(x, length(x)) for x in split(sen, " ")]
return((word))
end

LongestWord("Hello, how are you? nested, punctuation?")
```

But I haven't manage to find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex too. It only needs a slight change from @Bogumil's answer:

```
julia> function LongestWord2(sen::AbstractString)
           words = matchall(r"\w+", sen)
           words[findmax(length.(words))[2]]
       end
LongestWord2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> LongestWord2("Hello, how are you? nested, punctuation?")
"punctuation"
```

This way you get rid of the punctuations and get the raw word back.

To consolidate the comments here's some further explanation:

`matchall()` takes a regex, in this case `r"\w+"` which matches word like substrings, so letters, numbers and lowercases and returns an array of strings that match the regex.

`length.()` is using the combination of the `length` function and `.` which broadcasts the operation across all elements of the array. So we're counting the length of each array element (word).

`Findmax()` returns a tuple of length 2 where the 2 argument gives us the index of the maximum element. I use this to subset the `words` array and return the longest word.

Comment: Thank you niczky12! 
Can you please explain to me this part of your code:
`words[findmax(length.(words))[2]]`

Why do you use the "." after length?

Comment: `.` applies `length` to all elements of the collection. Without it you would get the length of the collection. Also observe that `\w` in regex matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ only. Finally - in general it will be slower (but it is more elegant :)).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added these to the answer! It's actually pretty much par on with your function in terms of speed. 1081ns for yours and 891ns for my function with `BenchmarkTools` when applied to `const s = "Hello, how are you? nested, punctuation?"`.

Comment: Indeed. `LongestWord3` is a bit faster though (anyway - it is interesting that regexps are really fast :)).

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you want to retain punctuation and want to split only on space (`" "`). If this is the case then you can use `findmax`. Note that I have changed the order of `length(x)` and `x`. In this way you will find the longest word, and among words of equal maximum length you will find the word that is *last* when using string comparison. Also I put `AbstractString` in the signature of the function as it will work on any string:

```
julia> function LongestWord(sen::AbstractString)
           word = [(length(x), x) for x in split(sen, " ")]
           findmax(word)[1][2]
       end
LongestWord (generic function with 1 method)

julia> LongestWord("Hello, how are you? nested, punctuation?")
"punctuation?"
```

This is the simplest solution but not the fastest (you could loop through the original string by searching consecutive occurrences of space without creating `word` vector using `findnext` function).

Other approach (even shorter):

```
julia> function LongestWord3(sen::AbstractString)
           word = split(sen, " ")
           word[indmax(length.(word))]
       end
LongestWord3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> LongestWord3("Hello, how are you? nested, punctuation?")
"punctuation?"
```

Comment: Thank you Bogumił Kamiński. The only problem with your solution is that now It only returns the maximum length and not the word

Comment: I tried to return the word in this way, but no success.

`function LongestWord(sen::String)
    word = [(length(x), x) for x in split(sen, " ")]
    return(word[findmax(length(word))])
end

LongestWord`

Comment: I have edited the reply to show you that actually my solution returns the longest word. I have also showed how to use your approach.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I found your answer interesting too. However your solution is not avoiding the punctuation, which remains still part of the answer.

Comment: My answer followed your question and in your code you did not remove punctuation. If you want to remove punctuation first you should define what "word" means to you (unfortunately this term has many possible definitions, e.g. `\w` pattern in regex is not a word letter definition in places where I live). If you define what you mean by  "word" - then I might think about an efficient solution (and regular expressions are a natural tool to use here).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shall be clearer next time!

Answer (score 0):

My version specifically defines what symbols are allowable (in this case letters, numbers and spaces):

```
ALLOWED_SYMBOLS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 \t\n"

function get_longest_word(text::String)::String
    letters = Vector{Char}()
    for symbol in text
        if uppercase(symbol) in ALLOWED_SYMBOLS
            push!(letters, symbol)
        end
    end
    words = split(join(letters))
    return words[indmax(length.(words))]
end

@time get_longest_word("Hello, how are you? nested, punctuation?")

"punctuation"
```

I doubt it's the most efficient code in the world, but it pulls 'ANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM' out of a 45,000-word dictionary in about 0.1 seconds. Of course, it won't tell me if there is more than one word of the maximum length! That's a problem for another day...